# jQuery UI: moving items from one list to another

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable

While this *should* be relatively straightforward, I can't figure out how to move (rather than copy) `LI` elements between `UL`s.

All I want is to drag any item from list *foo* to list *bar* (or vice versa) without duplicating the element.

While `connectToSortable` does almost exactly what I want (though I'd prefer to avoid `sortable`), it clones the element - and manually removing the original element by reacting to the `stop` event turns out to be not so easy (e.g. ensuring that a valid drop actually happened).

A simple "hello world" example would help me greatly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A Hello World example can be found here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists. You don't need a `draggable` at all, only a `sortable`.

```
$(function() {
    $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
        connectWith: '.connectedSortable'
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

If you want to disallow the sorting of items within one list, this may be a way to go. It's not the most beautiful UI though (the user is given false hope), and the user is also free to determine the drop position in a foreign list.

```
$(function() {
    var sender;
    var recvok = false;
    $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
        connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
        start: function() {
            sender = $(this);
            recvok = false;
        },
        over: function() {
            recvok = ($(this).not(sender).length != 0);
        },
        stop: function() {
            if (!recvok)
                $(this).sortable('cancel');
        }
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

This is a really horrible function working around what I feel is an incompleteness in jQuery UI. It saves the sender on sortstart and takes down a flag allowing drop. When another receiver is entered, it checks if it's not the sender and puts the flag up. On sortstop the flag is checked. Warning: this function is ugly to the eye of both the user and the programmer, but it works.

Comment: Do you want your users to be able to sort the items within one list? There's also a way to disable that.

Comment: Hrm, it appears the receive event is only fired if the respective items originates from a different list - so regular sorting is not covered.

Comment: There you go... this should work. I edited the answer. You can see it in action here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/aDugh/1/

Comment: Is there a way to constrain the drag and drop so it only occurs in 1 direction (i.e. from the first to the second list only and not vice-versa)?