# One Way Drag and Drop Between Two Lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm using the following JS code which I obtained from [jQuery UI: moving items from one list to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053201/jquery-ui-moving-items-from-one-list-to-another/3053300):

```
$("#list-one, #list-two").sortable({
                    connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
                    start: function () {
                        sender = $(this);
                        recvok = false;
                    },
                    over: function () {
                        recvok = ($(this).not(sender).length != 0);
                    },
                    stop: function () {
                        if (!recvok)
                            $(this).sortable('cancel');
                    }
                }).disableSelection();
```

This code allows drag and drop from the first to the second list and vice-versa. I only want drag and drop to work in one direction, from the first to the second list. Is this possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just change the attribute connectWith: here i refuse to drag from list2 to list1..

```js
  $("#list-one, #list-two").sortable({
                    connectWith: '#list-two',
                    start: function () {
                        sender = $(this);
                        recvok = false;
                    },
                    over: function () {
                        recvok = ($(this).not(sender).length != 0);
                    },
                    stop: function () {
                        if (!recvok)
                            $(this).sortable('cancel');
                    }
                }).disableSelection();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Connect lists</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #sortable1, #sortable2 {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    width: 142px;
    min-height: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {
    margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 
<ul id="list-one" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>
 
<ul id="list-two" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
</ul>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

another solution is to prevent the mousedown event on second list, but you cant reorder the list

```js
  $('#list-two li').mousedown(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   event.stopPropagation();
  });

  $("#list-one, #list-two").sortable({
                    connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
                    start: function () {
                        sender = $(this);
                        recvok = false;
                    },
                    over: function () {
                        recvok = ($(this).not(sender).length != 0);
                    },
                    stop: function () {
                        if (!recvok)
                            $(this).sortable('cancel');
                    }
                }).disableSelection();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Connect lists</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #sortable1, #sortable2 {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    width: 142px;
    min-height: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {
    margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 
<ul id="list-one" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>
 
<ul id="list-two" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
</ul>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```